USB Flash drive showing unreasonably large size
I have a USB/voice recorder formatted as FAT32. It shows up as HSD Technology USB Device, it has the size of 8GB and wouldn't allow me to convert it to NTFS. I have moved to it a 5GB folder but when I try seeing this folder's properties, it shows up as 195 TB and it is impossible to delete the folder.


Any idea what is happening?

@Gantendo I tried some time ago, it failed.

@JoepvanSteen I cannot upload files here or do not know.

Take a screenshot, then Edit your post and add the image file.

Folder likely can't be deleted because subfolders within it are Read Only - remove that attribute via the GUI folder Properties or via attrib -r F:\TFSSolution /d /s, then delete it, or it can be deleted without doing so via del /f /q F:\TFSSolution

It is highly likely the filesystem is corrupted. You should format it, but use the voice recorders (hopefully built-in) functionality to do so.

@DanielB There is no such functionality.
